# Right align an absolute positioned element to the edge of its ancestor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an absolute positioned element that's already anchored to its direct parent. My current design spec requires a couple of these elements to right align to the very end of the ancestor container. I'm trying to find these coordinates in jQuery but no matter what I try I just can't seem to get the right calculations. My first thought was to set the child's offset to the total width of the topmost container and subtract the child's width but since there's padding in both it's kind of thrown off. What am I missing here? Is there a better way to accomplish this? Unfortunately I have to keep the parent and child position properties.

```js
$('.child').offset({
  top: $('.parent').offset().top / 2,
  left: $('.container').outerWidth() - $('.child').outerWidth()
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <nav id="menu">
    <div class="parent">
      Parent
      
      <span class="child">Child</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not put `right: 0` to child element without jQuery?

Comment: `right: 0` is what aligns an absolutely positioned element to the right edge of the bounding box of the ancestor element. Also, since there are multiple coordinate systems involved with CSS -- page, document, viewport and those of elements themselves -- you'd need to specify in your question which coordinates you are trying to find. But if you just want to align an element along the right edge, no JavaScript (or JQuery) is necessary -- `right: 0` is all you need, assuming you set up the correct ancestor element as the containing block.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something but I don't see why you need Jquery here. A simple [float: right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) would work perfectly.

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <nav id="menu">
    <div class="parent">
      Parent
      
      <span class="child">Child</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Since you said you are not allowed to use float, here is an example using flex :

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <nav id="menu">
    <div class="parent">
      Parent
      
      <span class="child">Child</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: My design constraints don't allow me to unfortunately.

Comment: Could you add more information on what you are allowed to use ? Also, maybe your problem isn't there. You should be able to use a float, it's a pure css property.

Comment: @CarlEdwards I've edited my answer to incorporate the use of flex.

Comment: Can this be accomplished still having absolute on the child though?

Comment: @CarlEdwards  I don't think so, but you could remove this property using Jquery / Javascript,

Comment: That's the thing. I need absolute in there. I'm dealing with a really unintuitive design spec.

Comment: Can you make another class for this particular element ?

Comment: What are you thinking?

Comment: Well, if you are using the `.child` class somewhere else and that's why you can't remove it's `position: absolute` property, you could simply create a new class for the element you are trying to move right. This element would have two class and the new class would override the `position: absolute` property. This way, this element would be in the right position and all the other element that has the `.child` class would not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `transform` property for vertical centering and do `right: 0%` for keeping it fixed at the right end.

```css
   #container {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .parent {
      position: relative;
    }

    .child {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0%;
      transform: translate(0%,-50%);
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <nav id="menu">
        <div class="parent">
          Parent
          <span class="child">Child</span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone lands here looking for a react-tailwind solution, you can do something like this:

```
<div className="relative">
  <div className="absolute left-full top-0" />
</div>
```